# how to get all playlist urls in my youtube library (https://www.youtube.com/feed/library) using pytube?

Tags: python, pytube

I'm trying to get all the playlist urls (not the video urls inside the playlist).
for example let's say I created two playlists on youtube (playlist 1 and playlist 2)

I'm trying to do something like this

```
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/library'
playlists = pytube.playlists(url)
for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists):
    print(f'playlist {i}: {playlist.url}')

output:
playlist 1: 'url 1'
playlist 2: 'url 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
from pytube import Playlist

playlists = ["playlist_url1", "playlist_url2"]

for i, playlist_url in enumerate(playlists):
    print(f'playlist {i+1}: {Playlist(playlist_url).playlist_url}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upload all your playlists to your YouTube channel and do this

```
from pytube import Playlist, Channel
from os import system


def find_ids(key, var):
    if hasattr(var, 'items'):
        for k, v in var.items():
            if k == key:
                yield v
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                for result in find_ids(key, v):
                    yield result
            elif isinstance(v, list):
                for d in v:
                    for playlist_id in find_ids(key, d):
                        yield playlist_id


def find_urls(key, var):
    ids = set(find_ids(key, var))
    for id in ids:
        url = f'https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list={id}'
        yield url


def shutdown():
    system("shutdown /s /t 1")


channel_url = ''
channel = Channel(channel_url)
urls = list(find_urls('playlistId', channel.initial_data))

for i, url in enumerate(urls):
    playlist = Playlist(url)
    print(f'{i + 1}. {playlist.title}')
    output_path = f'D:\\{playlist.title}\\'

    # physically downloading the audio track
    for j, video in enumerate(playlist.videos):
        audio = video.streams.get_audio_only()
        audio.download(output_path)
        print(f'\t{j + 1}. {video.title}')

    print('-' * 100)

shutdown()
```